# How to read all the font sizes used in a docx

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using docx4j and the very useful webapp they've built for parts list: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html

I have a sample document with five words. First four are in font size 12 and the last is in font size 8.

I would like to read all the different font sizes used in the document. So in this case: 12 and 8

I uploaded the sample document on the webapp and I think this information would be stored in `document.xml` but I'm not certain as I only see `16` but not `24` in the xml. Also, I'm not certain how to extract this information.

**Questions**

- How can I extract font size of the word content in docx4j?
- How can I extract the font color of each word and background color of the entire word document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the font size is not set on the run, and a style is in use, you need to check the style hierarchy.  If it is not set there, it comes back to defaults.

As ECMA 4ed Part 1 puts it in 17.7.2 (Style Hierarchy):

> This process can be described as follows:
>
> - First, the document defaults are applied to all runs and paragraphs in the document.
> - Next, the table style properties are applied to each table in the document, following the conditional formatting inclusions and
>     exclusions specified per table.
> - Next, numbered item and paragraph properties are applied to each paragraph formatted with a numbering style.
> - Next, paragraph and run properties are applied to each paragraph as defined by the paragraph style.
> - Next, run properties are applied to each run with a specific character style applied.
> - Finally, we apply direct formatting (paragraph or run properties not from styles). If this direct formatting includes numbering, that
>     numbering + the associated paragraph properties are applied.
>
> If the value of the rFonts element (§17.3.2.26) references a font
>   which is not available, applications determine a suitable alternative
>   font via a process called font substitution, which is defined in
>   §17.8.2.

docx4j does something like this - see for example line 430 and ff in https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/PropertyResolver.java

Similar principles apply to font color.

I don't address here how to iterate through the document word by word (or rather, run by run), other than to say google traversalutil

**Example of setting font size explicitly in a run**

```
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>this is 18 points</w:t>
                </w:r>
```

You can set that in Microsoft Word, or using docx4j.  To see how to do it in docx4j, you can use to the webapp to generate code from a sample docx, but the essence is:

```
    org.docx4j.wml.R  yourRun;
    yourRun.getRPr().setSz(an HpsMeasure);
```

Comment: Answer updated.  If its "not set on the run", that w:sz element will not be present.

Comment: yourRun.getRPr().getSz()